# How do you combine a number and a string without printing the outcome in r

Tags: r, string, printing, numbers, cat

I am trying to combine a number (x=.9) and a string ("Area Under Curve:") together without printing.

I'm trying just to get the result of:
Area Under Curve: .9

cat() and paste() both print the result, however I want to assign the result to a new variable.

I tried using merge() and then toString() the result, but I got an annoying comma between the two objects.

Are there other functions that will combine the objects without printing them?

Comment: just assign it: `new_var <- paste('Area under a curve:', x)`

Comment: or if you **really** want to merge them and throw away the answer without printing, `invisible(paste(...))` :-)  (@onyambu, please post as an answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can go ahead and combine them using `paste` and store in a new variable:

```
new_var <- paste('Area under a curve:', x)
```

or even use `sprintf`:

```
 new_var <- sprintf('Area under a curve: %f', x)
```